# While resampling, put NaN in the resulting value if there are are missing values in the source interval

Tags: python, pandas, series

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

rng = pd.date_range("2000-01-01", periods=12, freq="T")
ts = pd.Series(np.arange(12), index=rng)
ts["2000-01-01 00:02"] = np.nan
ts
```

```
2000-01-01 00:00:00     0.0
2000-01-01 00:01:00     1.0
2000-01-01 00:02:00     NaN
2000-01-01 00:03:00     3.0
2000-01-01 00:04:00     4.0
2000-01-01 00:05:00     5.0
2000-01-01 00:06:00     6.0
2000-01-01 00:07:00     7.0
2000-01-01 00:08:00     8.0
2000-01-01 00:09:00     9.0
2000-01-01 00:10:00    10.0
2000-01-01 00:11:00    11.0
Freq: T, dtype: float64
```

```
ts.resample("5min").agg(pd.Series.sum, skipna=False)
```

```
2000-01-01 00:00:00     NaN
2000-01-01 00:05:00    35.0
2000-01-01 00:10:00    21.0
Freq: 5T, dtype: float64
```

So far so good. The problem is that in the last interval (00:10-00:15) it *does* output a value, because there's no `NaN` there. But I don't want it to, because some values are missing.

I could use `min_count=5`, but this wouldn't always work (e.g. if I'm aggregating daily to monthly, there's a variable number of source steps in each target step—some months have 28 days, some 29, some 30, some 31).

Answer (score 2):

You can [`reindex` your time series](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) using some simple arithmetic logic.

For example,

```
freq = 5
add = freq - tt.minute % freq
new_ts = ts.reindex(pd.date_range(ts.index[0], 
                                  ts.index[-1].to_datetime64() + pd.Timedelta(minutes=add-1), 
                    freq='T'))
```

which outputs

```
2000-01-01 00:00:00     NaN
2000-01-01 00:05:00    35.0
2000-01-01 00:10:00     NaN
Freq: 5T, dtype: float64
```

Comment: OK, what is `tt`?

Comment: @AntonisChristofides `td.index[-1]`